# HTML Overflow to a new line

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="width:300px">
<input type="text" id="t1" width="140px">
<input type="text" id="t2" width="140px">
<input type="text" id="t3" width="140px">
</div>
```

The third textbox is gettibg overflowed. I want to place the third text in new line through css. Is it possible?

Comment: create a JSFiddle to demonstrate what you mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you make a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your question...

Comment: But the third input is actually placed in new line by itself, so what do you want from us? :D If I'm not halucinating http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/cVyTZ/ Do you have any css set? If so just post us your css code too.

Comment: Why don't you use a `<br>`?

Comment: I think his question its explicit enougth, why all the down votes?

Comment: sorry, Actually I'm using a table..I can't use <br/>..

Comment: Why did you remove the code?  How do you expect an answer when there's nothing to work with?

Comment: yeah @User leave your code to other users with the same question can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, simply float left the two first inputs, your code stays like this:

HTML:

```
<div style="width:300px">
<input type="text" id="t1" width="140px">
<input type="text" id="t2" width="140px">
<input type="text" id="t3" width="140px">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#t1{
  float:left;
}
#t2{
  float:left;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WaZXm/)

Comment: How is this any different than what the original code already does?  http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/cVyTZ/

Comment: this answers his question that was "I want to place the third text in new line through css" and in your fiddle the second textbox is in a new line not only the third.

Comment: The OP doesn't specify that the 2nd input should not be on a new line, only that the 3rd one should be.

Comment: if he only specify the third, i assum its only the third he wants, but you could be right

Answer (score 1):

It should not overflow with the code you provide.

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/zZueP/

You must have other rules applied, (*perhaps an `white-space:nowrap` on the `div` element*) which you will need to remove/correct.